# check the status is active or not in middleware

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-middleware

I have a table called `agents` and I want to check in `middleware` when the agent is trying to log in, the agent is active or not

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
   {
      $user = $this->auth->user();

      if(agentmodel::where('status') == 'active'){
           true;
      }else{
           false;
      }
}
```

Comment: Answered your own question there

Comment: actually this code not working in middleware

Comment: Do you getting any error message?

Comment: not send any error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to return the request in the middleware so it continues

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    // Declared but not used
    $id = auth()->id();
    // If agent belongs to a user
    if (App\agentmodel::where('user_id', $id)->first()->status == 'active') {
        return $next($request);
    }
    \Session::flush();
    return back()->with('error', 'Your account is not active');
}
```

This will redirect back and not allow the user to continue if the agent is not active

Comment: not working and ```$user = auth()->user();``` m using this for checing admin or not

Comment: You are redirecting the active users back.

Comment: no, if not active m doing ```\Session::flush();``` and return with an error message like your account is not active

Comment: Updated, and yeah as if the accepted answer is doing exactly that. Brilliant

Answer (score -3):

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
      $user = $this->auth->user();
      $agent = AgentModel::where("status", "active")->get();

      if(count($agent) > 0) {
           return $next($request);
      } else {
           return back();
      }
}
```

Comment: @Ogreucha I just want to update condition correctly. Let's me update my answer

Comment: @SokChanty how do you know that current user is active or not? You just counting the active agents.